# TFS commandline multiple workspaces commit

Tags: unix, command-line, tfs

I have multiple TFS workspaces. Each workspace mapped to a specific directory on the server.

for example:

```
          Unix                    TFS server
/user/shared/Proj/primary -> $/Proj/primary
/user/shared/Proj/secondary -> $/Proj/secondary
...and so on
```

Now I have named the first workspace primary and second workspace secondary.

If I did

```
tf add –recursive *
tf checkin -recursive /user/shared/Proj/primary -comment:"test commit"
```

I dont see `$/Proj/primary` code got changed/updated. How do I make commit to both spaces?

Comment: Did you try `tf checkin -recursive $/Proj`?

Comment: it says the workspace could not determined from argument path. I am pretty sure it is "tf checkin -recursive (local path)"

Comment: On the Windows client, the server path works, it's how you can do the scenario you describe on Windows, I don't use the cross platform commandline enough to give you this answer on Linux

Comment: What's unclear to me too is whether you have one workspace with multiple folder mappings or multiple workspaces. You can check in across multiple mappings in the same workspace. You can't check in across multiple workspaces.

Comment: no each workspace is mapped to a different locations. Each workspace has its own individual work fold and paths.

Comment: Then you can't commit in a single checkin.

Comment: @logger Did you get any response from command line after running `tf checkin`?

Comment: after i delete the workspace and recreate workspace do a re-add it did work but unfortunately, it hangs at the end saying timeout when i attempted to check in. (i am suspecting there was something in the workspace in the previous run contain conflict either between paths or code that might prevent the checkin)

Comment: Did you get a conflicts window?

Comment: no i dont see it.

Comment: Create a new workspace and get the source from TFS, and have another try to see whether your issue persists.

Comment: that worked. After i deleted .tfs file from the workspace and recreate a new workspace it finally got through.

Comment: @logger Glad to know that you have resolved the issue, you could post the solution as an answer and accept it. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of this problem by deleting `.tfs` hidden file in the unix directory. It seems `.tfs` would have all the local workspace data stored including the workspace itself. Deleting this would basically remove any corrupted files, conflict, and other unwanted stuff from your workspace, since it elimiates workspace on that path. All you need to do to follow up is to recreate a new workspace and redo the commit on the same path to get to where you left off from before.